# Google Play Games API, 2 leaderboards

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Is there a way that I get all of the leaderboards that I added in my Google Play developer Console and showed them in my app? I know that there is a piece of code that displays only one of them:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
    LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
and the result is this:
```

[image: leaderboard]

Is there a way of displaying the two leaderboards and than the user to choose which one to see, instead of adding two buttons for each leaderboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I used the android studio suggestions to find out that there is a dedicated intend for this purpose. I changed my code to this:

```
if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(
                    mGoogleApiClient), 2);
```

Now all of my leaderboards are displayed when I pless my "leaderboards" button